# How to plot a region of integration of a bidimensional function?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I need to plot the region of the following integration

$$
\int^{3}_{1}\int^{4}_{0}(e^{x}+y)dydx
$$

```
Integrate[Exp[x] + y, {x, 1, 3}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: What do you mean, "plot the region". Draw the region of integration? Plot the integrand in a 3D plot as a function of `x` an `y`? Etc.

Comment: @march Yes, Exactly what you've said! The both, plot the integrand  together with the region of integration.

Comment: So, like, `Plot3D[Exp[x] + y, {x, 1, 3}, {y, 0, 4}]`?

Comment: I don't think, because I need to plot the region of integration together with this!

Comment: But what do you mean, "plot the region of integration"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @march Let me try, sorry for complicating this. I need to plot the integrand function and discriminate the region of integration in the same plot! That's the point! :)

Comment: This? `Plot3D[{Exp[x] + y, 0}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -1, 5}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 <= x <= 3 && 0 <= y <= 4], Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 30]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34118/discussion-between-wayner-klen-and-march).

Comment: @march Take a look at chat!

Comment: @WaynerKlën Cara! Muito boa pergunta e gostei da resposta do [rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103790/how-to-plot-a-region-of-intregration-of-a-bidimensional-function/103821#103821)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Exp[x] + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -2, 6}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None],
 Plot3D[{Exp[x] + y, 0}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -1, 5}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 1 <= x <= 3 && 0 <= y <= 4], 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.7]],
 ImageSize -> 700
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

The domains of the two integrals are $[1,3]$ and $[0,4]$.  These can be denoted using the [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) symbol.  Then the direct way to get the 2D domain is to take the Cartesian product of these two intervals:

```
domain = RegionProduct[Interval[{1, 3}], Interval[{0, 4}]]
(* Rectangle[{1, 0}, {3, 4}] *)
```

Plot the domain:

```
RegionPlot[domain]
```

Plot the function over the domain in various ways:

```
Plot3D[Exp[x] + y, {x, y} ∈ domain]
DensityPlot[Exp[x] + y, {x, y} ∈ domain]
ContourPlot[Exp[x] + y, {x, y} ∈ domain]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
Plot3D[Exp[x] + y, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 1, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Imagem]